# Uncaught TypeError: owl.owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, owl-carousel

Before anything else, let me say that I have looked at other similar questions here and I still can't figure this out.

I'm trying to build a website, using .NET MVC (razor) using a [this free template](http://freehtml5.co/preview/?item=crew-free-html5-bootstrap-template) I found online.

What I did, was to replace all the markup of my Index.chstml view with the html code of the template. Moved all the scripts and css files to the corresponding folders in my solution, and changed the html to correctly reference the new paths as required.

Needless to say that the original template works perfectly. But for some reason I really can't figure out I'm getting the error:

```
     Uncaught TypeError: owl.owlCarousel is not a function
```

I looked at the developer tools (chrome) and the scrips are there, so the only thing I can think of is something related to the loading order. Off course I didn't change that, so I wonder if razor did it somehow.

This is how my script loading section looks like:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.waypoints.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/owl.carousel.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/main.js")"></script>
```

and the problem happens inside main.js, right here:

```
    owl.owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        loop: true,
        margin: 0,
        responsiveClass: true,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        smartSpeed: 500,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        navText: [  
          "<i class='icon-arrow-left2 owl-direction'></i>",
          "<i class='icon-arrow-right2 owl-direction'></i>"
        ]
    });
```

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: the `owl` shouldn't be a `<div>` element/reference? the example I saw was using a div (with jQuery) like this: `$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({`

Comment: Yes you are right, I ommited that here, but it is (should be): var owl = $('.owl-carousel'); I looked however in the code and there's no div with that class. Worth to mention I didn't find such a div in the original template.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel a bit ashamed, but looks it was just a conflict between the scripts that the template uses, with the ones MVC razor includes by default.

I commented this at the Layout partial view:

@*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@

and voila! I realized that my code was loading more scripts than the original template.

Thanks everybody.